# Stop build when no changes from last build in HUDSON

Tags: hudson

HI. I'm new in hudson, and I have a quite silly question. When Hudson detect that there are no changes since the last build, does not stop the build? why?

I made a test job with a shell step command and always executes the command, have been changes in the repository or not.

How I can stop the build if no changes in the repository?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different types of *Build Triggers*.

I imagine you have configured your test job to "**Build Periodically**" which will just keep on building at the specified interval regardless of code changes.

If you choose "**Poll SCM**" then Hudson will poll your SCM for changes and only build if changes are detected.

Comment: Thaks for the quick answer.
It's just what I was looking for.